# Project missing in Localhost (WAMP)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp, wampserver

I got a copy of my project from work, and put it into the `www` folder of Wamp, in a different PC. However, when loading `localhost`, I am not able to see the folder in the list.

I attempted to create a few new folders, and they display correctly in localhost. Even if I rename this folder to something else, it still refuses to show up.

**This is what my `www` directory looks like :**
[image]

**And this is what `localhost` shows me:**
[image]

**Update :**
If I copy the files inside `mainProject` and paste them into either `test1` or `test2`, that folder disappears from `localhost` as well.

**Update 2:**
Deleting/Removing the `.htaccess` file from `mainProject` makes the folder visible in localhost, but when I try to access it, it gives me file not found error for obvious reasons! Can add snippets from the `.htaccess` file if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put anything into the \wamp\www folder, this is where the WAMPServer homepage lives in a file called index.php

So it looks from you first sentence that you have overwritten this file with one of your own projects files.

The simple solution is to install WAMPServer onto another PC and restore the \wamp\www folder from there. Alternatively uninstall WAMPServer, delete the \wamp folder and all subfolders, re-install WampServer and then copy your project into a sub folder of the \wamp\www folder. The wamp homepage is not actually required, but it can make life easier.

Also check the `wampserver.com/forum/en` there is a document there called 'WAMPServer 2.5 The Homepage, Your Projects Menu and the need for Virtual Hosts ' describing how to setup Virtual Hosts which also provides a more buttet proof environment to run a project in.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

Ok now you have undone the damage you did, you now need to learn how to create a Virtual Hosts for each of the projects you want to run/develop.

You can undo the changes you made to `Document Root, Directory and Virtual Host` in the httpd.conf file, these can all be individually set from within a Virtual host definition.

[See this post on the WampServer forum site](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,124482)

Comment: Did what you said, put the files back. Now it leads me to Wamp's index page, but I am still unable to access my folders!

Comment: I have also set my `Document Root`, `Directory` and `Virtual Host` (in `httpd.conf` ) to `c:\wamp\www\mainProject`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Followed those steps entirely, I set my virtual host alias to `testv1` , however `http://testv1/index.php` fails to load anything :( (File exists at location, btw). The error is simply "This webpage is not available".

DocumentRoot and Directory set back to default, and Vhost defined as shown in your link!

Comment: Was a problem in the hosts file definition. Thank you, your solution indeed fixed my problem! Cheers :)